# Difference between Varchar(max) and nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes

I came across a question while buidling schema for my application.

When to use `varchar(max)` and `nvarchar(max)`. I mean the exact use cases where it should be applied. I have surfed in net too but I was able to get the exact answer.

Could anyone suggest some exact usecase.

Comment: Say for example If i give varchar(max) and when my max data will 1000 characters and not beyond that(where i should give varchar(1000)). Is there will be memory or performance degradation as i give varchar(max) instead of 1000 Characters

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is for Microsoft **SQL Server**:

`NVARCHAR` is **Unicode** - 2 bytes per character, therefore max. of 1 billion characters; will handle East Asian, Arabic, Hebrew, Cyrillic etc. characters just fine.

`VARCHAR` is **non-Unicode** - 1 byte per character, max. capacity is 2 billion characters, but limited to the character set you're SQL Server is using, basically - no support for those languages mentioned before

Comment: You can't say 2 bytes per character unless dbms is specified! Implementation defined...

Comment: @jarlh: It's not implementation defined as `VARCHAR(MAX)` is SQL Server syntax, in Standard SQL there's a `CLOB`, `CHARACTER LARGE OBJECT` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it's SQL Server specific, thought other products have it too. (Why has the question no SQL Server tag...)

Answer (score 2):

Varchar(max)

Varchar fields can be of any size up to a limit, which varies by databases: an Oracle 9i database has a limit of 4000 bytes, a MySQL database has a limit of 65,535 bytes (for the entire row) and Microsoft SQL Server 2005 has a limit of 8000 characters (unless varchar(max) is used, which has a maximum storage capacity ...

nvarchar(max)

abcdefg n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for nvarchar are national char varying and national character varying.

Answer (score 0):

You should use nvarchar if you have to store unicode char. If you only store non-unicode-char you can use varchar.

Answer (score 0):

nvarchar is for unicode data, whilst varchar is uses only up to 8-bit codepage.
Use cases:
varchar is good when you're dealing with Latin letters in general, so let's say you have a blog and the language used to write to this blog is English, at this case varchar is a good option.
nvarchar is good when you're building a multilingual application, so you're using characters like Mandarin, Arabic ..etc.

Hope this helps.