# Nvarchar working with logical operator working?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just need your help here.

I have a table T

```
A (nvarchar)         B()
-------------------------- 
'abcd'
'xyzxcz'
```

B should output length of entries in A for which I did

```
UPDATE T
SET B = LEN(A)    -- I know LEN function returns int
```

But when I checked out the datatype of B using `sp_help T`, it showed column B as `nvarchar`.

What's going on ?

```
select A
from T 
where B > 100
```

also returned correct output?

Why is `nvarchar` working with logical operators ?

Please help.

Comment: Comparison operators do work with nvarchar values using dictionary order approach. Is B a defined column in your table? if yes, what type have you specified for that?

Comment: SQL Server has no moral compunctions whatsoever about implicitly converting `INT` to `CHAR` types and back. Extra insidious is that the `CHAR` -> `INT` conversion has higher priority than the other way around, so `B > 100` is implemented as `CAST(B AS INT) > 100`, and will fail if `B` contains a string that's not convertible this way. Needless to say, you should always take good care that columns are given appropriate types -- SQL Server won't complain if you don't, but reliability and performance will take a hit.

Comment: @sneh999 . . . The question simply does not make sense to me.  `UPDATE` does not change the type of a column.  The type is whatever the definition of the table is.  Why would you think `UPDATE` *would* change the type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017 where it is said that data types are converted explicitly or implicitly when you move, compare or store a variable. In your case, you are comparing column B with 100, forcing sql server to implicitly convert it to integer type (check the picture about conversions on the same page). As a prove, try to alter a row putting some text in column B and, after repeating your select query B>100, sql server will throw a conversione error trying to obtain an integer out of your text.

Answer (score 3):

It works because of implicit conversion between types.

[Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> **When an operator combines expressions of different data types, the data type with the lower precedence is first converted to the data type with the higher precedence.** If the conversion isn't a supported implicit conversion, an error is returned.
>
> Types precedence:
>
> ```
> 16. int
> ...
> 25. nvarchar (including nvarchar(max) )
> ```

In you example:

```
select A
from T 
where B > 100
     --nvarchar and int (B is implicitly casted to INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

when adding a column to a table in ssms, not adding a datatype a "default" datatype is chosen. for me on 2017 developer it's nchar(10). if you want it to be int define the column with datatype of int. in tsql it'd be

```
create table T (
     A nvarchar --for me the nvarchar without a size gives an nvarchar(2)
    ,B int
);

sp_help T

--to make a specific size, largest for nvarchar is 4000 or max...max is the replacement for ntext of old, as.
create table Tmax (
     A nvarchar(max)
    ,B int
);

--understanding nvarchar and varchar for len() and datalength()

select 
     datalength(N'wibble') datalength_nvarchar -- nvarchar is unicode and uses 2 bytes per char, so 12
    ,datalength('wibble') datalength_varchar -- varchar uses 1 byte per so 6
    ,len(N'wibble') len_nvarchar -- count of chars, so 6
    ,len('wibble') len_varchar -- count of char so still 6
```

[nvarchar(max) and varchar(max)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860230/difference-between-varcharmax-and-nvarcharmax)

hope this helps, the question is a bit discombobulated